# Objective C Method Retrieving Image

Tags: objective-c, methods, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm very sure this is an easy fix, but it's so specific I don't know where to find an answer... I want to create a method that retrieves and uses a UIImage from the object it is performed on.

Here is the line that calls the method with the imageView as the object.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(method:) withObject:self.imageView afterDelay:0.0];
```

and this is the method...

```
- (void) method:(UIImage *) image {

if ([image isEqual:image1]){
    x = 1;
}
if ([image isEqual:image2]){
    x = 2;
}
if ([image isEqual:image3]){
    x = 3;
}
if ([image isEqual:image4]){
    x = 4;
}
if ([image isEqual:image5]){
    x = 5;
}
```

...am I going about this in the right way? Thanks!

Comment: The parameter to `method` is `UIImage *`, not `UIImageView *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrive UIImage from UIImageView object you should just use

```
[self.imageView image];
```

And if you want to create a method that retrieves and uses a UIImage from the object it is performed on. (I will guess you are using an UIImageView object...) You should subclass or add category to the UIImageView and add a method like this to it

```
- (void) method {
   UIImage* image = [self image];
   //do whatever you want with the image
   //...
}
```

As an alternative you can pass an UIImageView to the method and let it retrieve the image and then use it for whatever purpose

```
- (void) method:(UIImageView*)imageView {
   UIImage* image = [imageView image];
   //do whatever you want with the image
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(method:) withObject:self.imageView.view afterDelay:0.0];
```

You are passing `UIImageview` as parameter rather than `UIImage`